# Provider Hosted App not listed in the App Part or Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, web-part, web-application

i have created a simple app and hosted it in azure then added it to app catalog on SharePoint online. I am able to add the web app to the site and are visible in the site content. But it is not showing up in the webpart section or app part section.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you will need to create **Client Web Part** in your SharePoint Hosted App. When you add Client Web Part in your SharePoint Hosted App solution and deploy it then you will find your App in **Insert >> App Part** ribbon.

You can use the default page that Client Web Part provide or else you can give path of your existing page that you already have been created in your App while adding Client Web Part.

You can find detail regarding how to create SharePoint Hosted App with Client Web Part [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/08/01/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-hosted-client-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

If you are using SharePoint Provider Hosted App then in that case also the mechanism is same. You can add Client WebPart. You can find more detail [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/include-an-add-in-part-in-the-provider-hosted-add-in)

Let me know whether it solves your problem or need more assist.

**Update:**

You can find the detail steps [here](http://sharepointpals.com/post/Creating-an-App-Part-and-Displaying-an-App-inside-the-App-Part-in-SharePoint-2013) which I have used in past and using it every Add-in.

Comment: So if i create a provider hosted app in azure you will not be able to add it to the wep part or app part section ?

Comment: i wasnt able to get it to work. I have added the Client Web Part  edited the element.xml file just to add   <Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/Tab.aspx?DisplayType=iframe" />

Comment: You dont need to edit the XML file. Just select the start page of the webpart in ClientWebPart, rest it will automatically maintain,